# QuillJs - jumps to top

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I'm using QuillJs as a text editor on my website. In a long post the screen view jumps to top when pasting text or changing heading type or alignment or color or inserting a link or video. Can't find out why.

QuillJs version: 1.2.6
Browser: Chrome 58.0.3029.110
OS: Windows 10

Initialization:

```
var toolbarOptions = [
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] },
       'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', { 'align': [] },
        { 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' },
        { 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], 

        ['image', 'blockquote', 'code-block', 'link', 'video'],

        ['clean']                                           
    ];
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

Comment: Have you added custom CSS? If so you may need to set the scrollingContainer configuration http://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#scrollingcontainer

Comment: Yes, there is custom css. But I don't know how to set scrollingContainer configuration properly. There is only mention about it on the quilljs website, but no detailed explanation.

Comment: I got it. If you want an editor to be scrolled and maintained by a web page main scrollbar, you need to set _scrollingContainer_ property to **'body'** during configuration of Quill object.

Comment: The scrollingContainer is used to specify which element has the scrollbars. In your case it sounds like body, but for others it may be some other element. It is common for some websites to have a #sidebar #header and #main container which scrolls and in that case you want the #main container as the scrollingContainer. Again it's whichever element has the scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for help, @jhchen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an editor to be scrolled and maintained by a web page's main scrollbar, you need to set **scrollingContainer** property to *'body'* during configuration of Quill object.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
    theme: 'snow',
    scrollingContainer: 'body'
});
```

Comment: note that if you are using a class name or id as the scrollingContainer it needs to be the selector. i.e : ".container-name" or "#container-name"

Comment: note that scrollingContainer should be without any "height:" CSS configuration as I had "html {heigth: 100% }" won't work.

Comment: scrollingContainer: 'html'
was the only solution for me.

Comment: @DarkScrolls, that worked for me as well, thank you! You should probably add it as an answer

Answer (score 8):

This happens when any option is clicked from the quill toolbar. I had similar issue and I was using react-quill 0.4.1.

Try using event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation on quill toolbar to fix this.

The following fixed the issue for me.

```
componentDidMount()
{
$('.quill-toolbar').on("mousedown", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Setting scrollingContainer to html was the only solution that worked for me:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
    theme: 'snow',
    scrollingContainer: 'html'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because of these two lines:

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/5715499c57091db262c176985f6c5370d73db5dd/modules/toolbar.js#L86

and

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/5b28603337f3a7a2b651f94cffc9754b61eaeec7/core/quill.js#L171

this.scrollingContainer => could be not an actual scrolling element.

The fix could be is to assign the nearest scrolling element directly.

If you are not sure what it is you can use this snippet to find it:

```
const regex = /(scroll)/;

const style = (node, prop) => window.getComputedStyle(node, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
const scroll = (node) => regex.test( style(node, "overflow") + style(node, "overflow-y") + style(node, "overflow-x"));
export const scrollparent = (node) => {
  return !node || node===document.body ? document.body : scroll(node) ? node : scrollparent(node.parentNode);
};
```

```
   editor.scrollingContainer = scrollparent(editor.container);
```